# Append Button into a collapsible content

Tags: jquery, listview, button, mobile, jsfiddle

I am trying to append a button into collapsible content but it is not showing up like a normal button.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/76buh/1/

How do I make the button look like a proper jquery mobile button?

```
$('#eventlist').listview('refresh');
$('#ev2').empty();
$('#ev2').append('<button id="settotrue">More Events</button>');
```

Comment: all you need is this `$('#ev').collapsible().trigger('create');` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/76buh/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let your application know that you created an element by triggering an event, and the framework will do the rest:

```
$('#ev2').append('<button id="settotrue">More Events</button>').trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose that script in pagecreate event so DOM will be modified before the jQuery Mobile enhance the elements

```
        $( '#thePage' ).live( 'pagecreate',function(event){
            $('#eventlist').append('<li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>')
            //$('#eventlist').listview('refresh');
            $('#ev2').empty();

            $('#ev2').append('<a href="#moreevents" data-role="button">more events</a> ');
        });
```

HTML changed to

```
 <div data-role="page" id="thePage">
```

Note that:

- I did the button as a link so you will not need to bind the click event on the button
- Also commented listview('refresh') as you can't call it in this event
- I've set the first div ID as 'thePage'

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated and is not recommended due to performance. Try `.on()` instead - http://api.jquery.com/live/